# how to redirect to the "operating" page in will_paginate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, will-paginate

I have a message box using **will_paginate**.
I have 6 messages showing in 3 pages, 
when i delete an item in page_3, it redirect_to page_1, how can i **still be in page_3**?!

Comment: You can start by showing us some code of how you implemented it

Answer (score 3):

2 ways to solve the issue:

1. "redirect_to :back"
2. save params[:page] and redirect to the page once item is deleted

Answer (score 1):

You can use method total_pages on instance variable which you are using for pagination.

```
example :
@user = User.find(params[:id])
@comments = @user.comments.paginate(:page => 1, :per_page => 20)
@comments.total_pages
```

@comment.total_pages will return you the last page no. which you can use for your redirection.