# Pagination in Rails - Always redirects to 1st page after edit/update an element belonging to the other pages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, pagination, will-paginate

I have used **will_paginate** gem for paginating index page of my test_app. It just shows the auctions listed and corresponding to each auction there is Edit, Destroy functionalities. My pagination is working good. I have 6 auctions in total listed in a table manner and as I put per_page = 2, 3 pages are there. But when I edit & Update the Auction in page 2 or 3, it just goes to 1st page after update action. I want that to stay on the same page.

My View - Index.html.erb

```
<h1>Listing auctions</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Category</th>
    <th>Item</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @auctions.each do |auction| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= auction.name %></td>
    <td><%= auction.category %></td>
    <td><%= auction.item_id %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', auction %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_auction_path(auction) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', auction, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />
<%= will_paginate @auctions %>
<%= link_to 'New Auction', new_auction_path %>
<%= link_to 'Back to Home', home_path %>
```

My Model - Auction.rb

```
class Auction < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :category, :item_id
  self.per_page = 2
end
```

My Controller - auctions_controller.rb

```
class AuctionsController < ApplicationController
  # GET /auctions
  # GET /auctions.json
  def index
    @auctions = Auction.paginate(:page => params[:page])#pagination for Index
    #@posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page])
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @auctions }
    end
  end

  # GET /auctions/1
  # GET /auctions/1.json
  def show
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @auction }
    end
  end

  # GET /auctions/new
  # GET /auctions/new.json
  def new
    @auction = Auction.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @auction }
    end
  end

  # GET /auctions/1/edit
  def edit
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /auctions
  # POST /auctions.json
  def create
    @auction = Auction.new(params[:auction])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @auction.save
        format.html { redirect_to @auction, notice: 'Auction was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @auction, status: :created, location: @auction }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @auction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /auctions/1
  # PUT /auctions/1.json
  def update
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @auction.update_attributes(params[:auction])
        format.html { redirect_to @auction, notice: 'Auction was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @auction.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /auctions/1
  # DELETE /auctions/1.json
  def destroy
    @auction = Auction.find(params[:id])
    @auction.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to auctions_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end
```

[image]

Please suggest a solution. Thank you.

Comment: Don't put urgent in your titles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `update` action, you have the auction id, there you can calculate the expected page no. accordingly and use 
`redirect_to @auction,:page=>page_no`

or otherwise you would have to send the `page` parameter to the edit page from the show(when edit link is clicked) and then to the update action to use that page no to redirect

Comment: How we can send the page_no from show to edit? can we use instance variable?

Comment: For that you would have to modify link of edit buttons and add pageno to it as `edit_auction_path(auction,:page=>pageno)`

Answer (score 3):

You need to retain **params[:page]** throughout edit/update operations and merge it with your query string

Comment: e.g. redirect_to @auction,:page => params[:page]

Comment: Where I need to specify that? I am using resourceful routing.

Answer (score 2):

Here is my solution:

1. In your index page which has edit/update button (add params page)

   ```
   = link_to content_tag(:span, "", :class => "fa fa-edit") + t('btn.edit'), edit_bill_path(bill, page: params[:page] || 1), :class => "btn btn-warning"
   ```
2. In you form (add hidden field page)

   ```
   = f.input :page, as: :hidden, input_html: {value: params[:page]}
   ```
3. In your controller (custom redirect path with page params)

   ```
   redirect_to your_path(page: params[:your_form_name_instance][:page]), notice: t('messages.update')
   ```
4. Enjoy :)

Answer (score 1):

This is what your delete method should look like in auctions_controller.rb if you want to just use :back for the redirect:

```ruby
   # DELETE /auctions/1
   # DELETE /auctions/1.json
   def destroy
     @auction.destroy
     respond_to do |format|
       format.html { redirect_to :back }
       format.json { head :no_content }
     end
   end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use method **total_pages** on instance variable which you are using for pagination.

you can refer [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6723992/how-to-redirect-to-the-operating-page-in-will-paginate/17521530#17521530) for details

Answer (score 0):

I used `{ redirect_to :back }` and it maintained the same page.

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but you can check for `request.referrer` if its available before showing redirecting to the deafault url using something like this in your edit, update or destroy actions:

```
  def destroy
    @post.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to (request.referrer || posts_url), notice: 'Post was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
```

---

You can also read how `devise` gem handles redirection in [this file here](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/controllers/store_location.rb)

Answer (score 0):

I found the best way to do this is utilize `redirect_back` in Rails 5+.

Example:

```
# DELETE /guests/1
# DELETE /guests/1.json
def destroy
  @guest.destroy
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { redirect_back(fallback_location: guests_url, notice: 'Guest was successfully destroyed.') }
    format.json { head :no_content }
  end
end
```

Basically it redirects to the referrer that referred to the destroy action. If there is no referrer `fallback_location` is used. For instance I have single button form on my index page that lists guests, and when the destroy button is clicked I am redirected back to the page where the guests are listed, the `page` param included!